# Why is the IP layer not removed by the kernel in the ping program

Tags: c, linux, ip, ping, icmp

I am looking into the standard ping implementation. Here the icmp structure is created and the data is filled in. The IP layer is added by the kernel. However when we receive a message using the function http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom I observe that they are first parsing the IP packet and then parsing the ICMp packet. Why is this happening. The code I am referrring to is the standard ping implementation available online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the header is always included when receiving an IPv4 packet on a raw socket. Notice the following in `raw(7)` (emphasis mine):

> The  IPv4  layer  generates an IP header when sending a packet unless the `IP_HDRINCL` socket option is enabled on the socket.  When it is enabled, the packet must contain an IP header.  *For receiving the IP header is always included in the packet.*

Since the header is always included and [has variable length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure) (for IPv4), it must be parsed to figure out where the ICMP data starts.

As for *why* the header isn't removed (sorry if that was the only thing you were wondering), I don't know. My wild guess is that enough programs that deal in raw IPv4 want to look at the header that it didn't seem worthwhile to include stripping it as an option. From a quick look it seems the header *is* stripped for IPv6.

The standard `ping` and `ping6` come from **iputils** by the way, where *ping_common.c*, *ping.c*, and *ping6.c* are the most relevant source files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is what I was looking for. I also observe that they right shift the length of the ip packet by 2. Why is this?

Comment: @GatsbyGreat: Which ping implementation are you looking at? Right-shifting by 2 would divide by 4, but I'm not sure why they'd do that.

Comment: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-307.0.1/ping.tproj/ping.c. I meant left shifting though

Comment: It's because the IHL field in the IP header specifies the number of 32-bit (4-byte) words. Multiplying that by four (which is the same as `<< 2`) gives the number of bytes.

Comment: Some of the behavior of raw sockets might be system-specific by the way, but it seems Linux and OS X act similarly here.